# Help construct a simple query Using 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hey guys need some more help

I have 3 tables `USERS, PROFILEINTERESTS and INTERESTS`

profile interests has the two foreign keys which link users and interests, they are just done by ID.

I have this so far

```
$statement = "SELECT
  InterestID
FROM
  `ProfileInterests`
WHERE
  userID = '$profile'";
```

Now I want it so that it selects from Interests where what it gets from that query is the result.

So say that gives out 3 numbers

```
1
3
4
```

I want it to search the Interests table where ID is = to those...I just don't know how to physically write it in PHP...

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using a JOIN:

Best option if you need values from the PROFILEINTERESTS table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.*
  FROM INTERESTS i
  JOIN PROFILEINTERESTS pi ON pi.interests_id = i.interests_id
 WHERE pi.userid = $profileid
```

### Using EXISTS:

```
SELECT i.*
  FROM INTERESTS i
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                 FROM PROFILEINTERESTS pi 
                WHERE pi.interests_id = i.interests_id
                  AND pi.userid = $profileid)
```

### Using IN:

```
SELECT i.*
  FROM INTERESTS i
 WHERE i.interests_id IN (SELECT pi.interests_id
                            FROM PROFILEINTERESTS pi 
                           WHERE pi.userid = $profileid)
```

Comment: I have it already getting the values from profileinterests it returns me what ever the variable profile is and what Interest ID's it has. What I want to do is get that interest ID and go to my Interests table and use the ID to look up a what is in that row and get that and put it in to a variable. Having a little trouble trying to explain it .

I do not want to join tables.

Comment: @Josip Gòdly Zirdum: All these queries retrieve information from the INTERESTS table, based on the PROFILEINTERESTS data.  A JOIN is one of the possible solutions.

Comment: @Josip - You should aim to use as few round trips to the database as possible, while it's perfectly possible to take the returned ID's and lookup the corresponding interest rows, i can't think of any situation where you would want to do that, the queries me and Ponies have provided will do the same thing with just 1 round trip.

Comment: Went with this method, it works. Just I'm having issues with smarty (the template designer thing for php)

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, lets say you execute the query above using this PHP code:

```
$statement = mysql_query("SELECT InterestID FROM `ProfileInterests` 
WHERE userID = '$profile'");
```

Then you can use a PHP loop to dynamically generate an SQL statement that will pull the desired IDs from a second table. So, for example, continuing the code above:

```
$SQL = "";

while ($statementLoop = mysql_fetch_assoc($statement)) {
//Note the extra space on the end of the query
  $SQL .= "`id` = '{$statementLoop['InterestID']}' OR ";
}

//Trim the " OR " off the end of the query
$SQL = rtrim($SQL, " OR ");

//Now run the dynamic SQL, using the query generated above
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE {$SQL}")
```

I haven't tested the code, but it *should* work. So, this code will generate SQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `id` = '1' OR `id` = '3' OR `id` = '4'
```

Hope that helps,
spryno724

Comment: Never do more trips back & forth between the database and the application than you need to - this uses resources you could never recoup.  And there's a risk of data no longer existing in the associated table for the subsequent queries.

Comment: I tried doing this, it did not work. Not sure why, 310am. I should probably sleep.

OMG ponies it's not for a huge project just an assignment, it does need to be very complex at all.

Comment: Error 1064 : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '246''' at line 1

Comment: That number "246" is the ID of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you want to join the tables

```
select
    i.Name
from
    ProfileInterests p
inner join
    interests i
on 
    p.interestid = i.interestid
where 
    p.userid = 1
```